# teardown method in unittest python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am new to python. I read unittest docs. In the documentation about tearDown() method, I found following lines

**"This is called even if the test method raised an exception, so the implementation in subclasses may need to be particularly careful about checking internal state."**

What does this statement conveys ? Can you let me understand me with the help of some good example, where the internal statement can create havoc ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

I got some answers, but they are quite simple. I need some examples, where some state is involved, like tests involving database and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OP:

**"This is called even if the test method raised an exception, so the implementation in subclasses may need to be particularly careful about checking internal state."**

The first things this conveys is that you can be sure that `teardown` is called whatever happens in your test methods. Consequently this means that you should *not* have any teardown code in your test method, you should move it into the `teardown` method.

However, if you do have an exception in your test method, this may mean that the state of your test instance may be different on different test runs and the `teardown` method must take this into account, or you must structure your code so that it will always work.

An example may be that you test code involves the creation of tables in the database. If you have an exception, then maybe not all the tables are created, so `teardown` should make sure it doesn't try to drop non-existent tables. However, the better way might be for `setup` to start a transaction and `teardown` to rollback the transaction.

Comment: This is more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `tearDown()` method is executed regardless if your test method passed or failed (raised an exception).

For example:

```
def tearDown():
    print 'In teardown: cleaning up'

def test_Example1():
    try:
        result = 2 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        raise e

def test_Example2():
    try:
       result = 2 / 2
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        raise e
```

When `test_Example1` runs, it will raise a `ZeroDivisionError`, and subsequently execute `tearDown()`, printing `In teardown: cleaning up` to the console. `test_Example2` will **not** raise a `ZeroDivisionError` exception, yet `tearDown()`will still be executed regardless.

**Edit** I am not entirely familiar with Python's database modules, but this should be enough to get the ball rolling...

```
def tearDown():
    print 'In teardown: cleaning up'

def test_do_database_task():
    db = sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME)        
    try:
        # code related to task at hand
    except:
        raise Exception("Error in connection!")
    finally:
        closeDb(db)
```

Comment: Can you give me some examples related to database, where some internal test state is involved ?

Comment: I might have upvoted your answer, but at present I don't have sufficient reputation score.